# Voltage regulator consume more current

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, current-measurement, high-current

I have used LP3961 3.3V regulator cicuit for my STM32 microcontroller circuit. I have implemented low power stop mode in STM32. Micro controller consumed 25uA itself. When I Measured the current consumption of whole circuit with regulator, It was 3.5 mA. I don't understand why the regulator takes much current than microcontroller. Do anyone know the reason?

Comment: What other stuff do you have on the board? Is there a high leakage organic polymer cap? A clock oscillator? Can you post a schematic?

Comment: What else is on the board? Lets see the full schematic. What are you measuring the 3.5mA with? Are you sure your ampmeter is sensitive enough?

Answer (score 5):

The [LP3961](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lp3961) has a typical quiescent current of 3 mA in normal operation. Look for another linear regulator or find a way to shutdown/enable the  LP3961.

[image]